# Efficient way select rows from a data frame based on multiple constraints

Tags: r

To setup my example, assume I have already performed a simple linear optimization with 4 variables (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`), where the "weights" and "values" of each run have a random component (meaning each run will likely have a different optimal solution). Given the results of 25 runs, I can create a dummy matrix which tells me whether or not each variable was included in the optimal solution for each one. Use the following as an example:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

Run <- 1:25
A <- sample(c(0,1), 25, T)
B <- sample(c(0,1), 25, T)
C <- sample(c(0,1), 25, T)
D <- sample(c(0,1), 25, T)

df <- data.frame(Run, A, B, C, D)
```

Now that I have this dummy matrix with the results, I want to be able to select exactly 10 rows, such that the selected 10 rows meet summary constraints for `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` (there will be multiple solutions). For example, say that I want to select 10 rows such that `A` is included over 5 times and the other 3 variables are included 2 to 7 times, is there a library or algorithm that would automate this?

It feels like I could honestly just do another `lpsolve` optimization, but I'm having trouble thinking how I would build it to get exactly 10 (or `n`) results. There also wouldn't be an objective or direction to the optimization. Could I just make 2 more dummy variables `v1` and `v2` that are both `rep(1, 25)`, and then say `v1` must equal 10 with the objective is to maximize `v2` (which will always be 10)? Along with my other constraints of course.

Thanks for any and all suggestions.